# lftp bash script end of file unexpected

Tags: bash, lftp

I'm trying to put the result in a variable but it didn't work
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")

```
#!/bin/bash
test="$(lftp -u ns454575.ip-154-145-259.eu,NGFYv85MTI ftpback-rbx2-588.mybackup.ovh.net << EOF
cd /backup/site
ls
bye
EOF)"
```

[image]

Comment: EOF)"?.........

Comment: I'm trying to put the result in a variable <<delimiter ... delimiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add something after here docs. You can validate this by using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
test="$(lftp -u ns454575.ip-154-145-259.eu,NGFYv85MTI ftpback-rbx2-588.mybackup.ovh.net <<-EOF
cd /backup/site
ls
bye
EOF
)"
```

p.s. you know that `test` is a command as well? :-)